# checkout_cart_update_items_before

Tags: magento2, cart, event-observer

```
class CartProductUpdateAfter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');  
        $product = $item->getProduct();
}
```

the above code is giving error to  get `$item` and `$product` values in this page? what is the correct syntax to get those values on the shopping cart page?

Comment: this is working for me sales_quote_item_qty_set_after

Answer (score 2):

There's no such data called `quote_item` dispatched with this event:

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
    'checkout_cart_update_items_before',
    ['cart' => $this, 'info' => $infoDataObject]
);
```

First, you can retrieve the info data object by calling:

```
$infoDataObject = $observer->getEvent()->getInfo();
```

After that you can retrieve the entire cart:

```
$cart = $observer->getEvent()->getCart();
```

And then loop through the items:

```
foreach ($infoDataObject as $itemId => $itemInfo) {
    $item = $cart->getQuote()->getItemById($itemId);
    $product = $item->getProduct();
}
```

Comment: i am getting the error in  $item->getProduct();  i want get this below data $price = $product_attr->getData(100); //set your price here
            $item->setCustomPrice($price);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);